# grep for vista 64?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, grep

Does anyone know if there is a version of grep for vista x64?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it works fine with [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A quick search brings those questions/answers :

- [What are good grep tool for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows)
- [Is there a Pattern Matching Utility like GREP in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416241/is-there-a-pattern-matching-utility-like-grep-in-windows)

And those will point you to tools like [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/), the Findstr tool that's bundled with windows, or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) -- or others ^^

Answer (score 1):

`grep.exe` from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) works fine with WoW64.

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.wingrep.com/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest considering the option of stepping slightly sideways:

You can do the equivalent quite easily using powershell by pipelining a get-childitem into a select-string.

Powershell is an impressive tool for playing with windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell:

> findstr -s "keyword|regex" *.txt

This is just an example of one grep feature. There are other ways to do much more complex things as well.

Comment: `findstr` also works in Command Prompt